# How to replace a directory with the same name with new one?

Tags: c#, directory

I am putting a check that if a directory by a name exists then it should delete that directory and replace it with the new one.
For that i am having this code:

```
if (Directory.Exists(b))
{
    Directory.Delete(b);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(b);
}
```

where b is the name of the directory for which i am outting the check.
I am getting a run time error that 
Directory is not empry, what shall i do?

Answer (score 5):

Try Directory.Delete(b, true)

Comment: See link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.delete.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If the directory isn't empty you'll need to go in enumerate all the files and delete those first.

You'll also have to recurse down any subfolders too.

Or just call `Directory.Delete(folder, true)` of course!

Comment: See link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.delete.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You must call `Directory.Delete(path, true)` to force the deletion of subdirectories and files.

Answer (score 2):

Delete subdirectories and files by setting a second boolean parameter to true:

```
if (Directory.Exists(b))
{
    Directory.Delete(b, true);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(b);
}
```